# Can't bind static property in XAML (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, forms, xaml, xamarin, binding

I have a static class (`Evp`), which is located in `Models` folder. It has a `Name` string, with getter and setter and a `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and its code:

```
public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
private static string _name
public static string Name{
    get => _name;
    set{
        _name = value;
        OnStaticPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

In my XAML file, this is how I tried to bind (it worked in WPF 4.5 if I recall correctly):

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Beige" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Models:Evp.Name}}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30"></Label>
```

I specified the `Models` folder in the `ContentPage` in XAML:

```
xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:Rdb.Models;assembly=Rdb"
```

For some reason, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?
Also, how can I set this binding in code-behind?

Comment: {Binding Source={x:Static Models:Evp}, Path=Name}

Comment: Does your class implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Comment: I can't use interfaces with static classes sadly.

Comment: {Binding Source={x:Static Models:Evp}, Path=Name}

It gives me an error before the comma: " , expected". Strange. I guess this will be some easy task, but I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To support data binding, your class has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Unfortunately, static classes cannot implement interfaces, so your solution will not work.

The solution would be to create a normal class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then create a singleton instance of this class which you will register as a resource:

```
App.Current.Resources["Evp"] = new Evp();
```

And then you reference it with `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource Evp}}
```

To ensure the class is singleton would be a `public static` get-only property:

```
public static Evp Instance {get;} = new Evp();
```

And you would then also add a `private` constructor to make sure others cannot create instances of your class:

```
private Evp()
{
}
```

The resource would then be set as:

```
App.Current.Resources["Evp"] = Evp.Instance;
```

This makes using your class in C# code easier by just using `Evp.Instance`.